# Optimize a function that analyses a String

Tags: java, performance, processing-efficiency, monte-carlo-tree-search

I'm currently programming an MCTS AI for a game and I want to optimize the CPU bottlenecks. One method takes about 20% of all processing and returns to what team a piece/base on a position on a 2D String belongs. Bases are formatted as "b:000" where 000 is the teamId. Pieces are formatted as "p:000_1" where 000 is the teamId. All I want to do is get the 000 from the Id String as efficient as possible.

Currently my Code is the following:

```
public static int getOccupantTeam(String[][] grid, int[] pos, StringBuilder sb) {
    sb = sb.delete(0, sb.length()).append(grid[pos[0]][pos[1]]);
    int indexUnderscore = sb.indexOf("_");
    return Integer.parseInt(sb.substring(sb.indexOf(":")+1, indexUnderscore == -1 ? sb.length() : indexUnderscore));
  }
```

The StringBuilder is to reduce the amount of created Objects as I can create it once and use it as often as I want.
Is there any way to make my code more efficient?

Comment: do these need to be strings? Maybe make a class that encapsulates this info.  If the Ids could be numbers, comparison operations will be much faster.

Comment: For me it is a smell that you first concatenate everything into one big StringBuilder and then cut that again with substring to parse it. What is the structure of `grid`, can you maybe work directly with that instead of concatenation? Maybe we could help you better if you provide some examples of the input data and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

As a comment already says, you’re better off fixing the overall design. Use dedicated objects instead of formatted strings.

But if you want to keep the logic:

What’s striking is the entirely pointless use of a `StringBuilder` here. You’re emptying the builder at the beginning (via `sb.delete(0, sb.length())`), followed by copying a single string into it, just to perform operations on the `StringBuilder` which you could do on the original `String` in the first place.

Besides that, since the location of the underscore is expected to be after the colon, you can search for the colon first and only search for the underscore after that position.

```java
public static int getOccupantTeam(String[][] grid, int[] pos, StringBuilder sb) {
    String s = grid[pos[0]][pos[1]];
    int start = s.indexOf(":") + 1, indexUnderscore = s.indexOf("_", start);
    return Integer.parseInt(
        s.substring(start, indexUnderscore == -1? s.length(): indexUnderscore));
}
```

You can, of course, remove the obsolete `StringBuilder` parameter now.

If you are using Java 9 or newer, you can omit the `substring` operation:

```java
public static int getOccupantTeam(String[][] grid, int[] pos) {
    String s = grid[pos[0]][pos[1]];
    int start = s.indexOf(":") + 1, indexUnderscore = s.indexOf("_", start);
    return Integer.parseInt(
        s, start, indexUnderscore == -1? s.length(): indexUnderscore, 10);
}
```

See [`Integer.parseInt(CharSequence s, int beginIndex, int endIndex, int radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.CharSequence,int,int,int))

Comment: I didn't want to create endless many String Objects when I call the method hundrets of thousands of times. I think Ill try the suggestion and implement Objects that hold information about a certain position in the grid, it's worth a try. Thank you

Comment: In the first variant, `substring` is the only operation creating a new `String` object and, of course, calling `substring` on a `StringBuilder` also creates a new `String` object. This is unavoidable when you need a `String` object for `parseInt`. You can’t create a `String` object without creating a `String` object. The Java 9+ solution avoids that. The `StringBuilder` did not add anything useful. The way you used it, it did not prevent any object creation but added several copying operations.

Answer (score 0):

### Strings

Drop the `b:` & `p:` prefixes as the length of the string distinguishes the base from the piece. Three characters means a base, more than 3 means a piece.

```
boolean isBase = ( string.length() == 3 ) ;
boolean isPiece = ( string.length() > 3 ) ;
```

To get the team number, you know the digits are always in the first three characters.

```
int teamId = Integer.parseInt( string.substring( 0 , 2 ) ) ;
```

### Objects

But as others suggested, you should be using smart objects rather than dumb strings.

Something like this quick-and-dirty demo.

Make an interface to cover both base and piece.

```java
package work.basil.example.game;

public interface GamePart
{
    int teamId ( );
}
```

Implement both base and piece. I would define them as a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) if their main purpose is to transparently communicate shallowly-immutable data.

```java
package work.basil.example.game;

public record Base ( int teamId ) implements GamePart
{
}
```

```java
package work.basil.example.game;

public record Piece ( int teamId , int id ) implements GamePart
{
}
```

Represent the board. The board holds elements of the type of the interface `GamePart`. The actual objects can be an instance of either of our two record classes, `Base` & `Piece`.

```java
package work.basil.example.game;

public class Board
{
    final GamePart[][] grid = new GamePart[ 8 ][ 8 ];

    GamePart gamePartAtIndices ( final int xIndex , final int yIndex )
    {
        return grid[ xIndex ][ yIndex ];
    }

    void placeGamePartAtIndices ( final int xIndex , final int yIndex , final GamePart gamePart )
    {
        this.grid[ xIndex ][ yIndex ] = gamePart;
    }

    String report ( )
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder( );
        for ( int row = 0 ; row < grid.length ; row++ )
        {
            for ( int column = 0 ; column < grid[ row ].length ; column++ )
            {
                stringBuilder.append( "Row: " ).append( row ).append( " | Column: " ).append( column ).append( " = " ).append( grid[ row ][ column ] ).append( System.lineSeparator( ) );
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString( );
    }
}
```

Drive the whole thing through a `Game` class.

```java
package work.basil.example.game;

public class Game
{
    final Board board = new Board( );

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Game game = new Game( );
        game.board.placeGamePartAtIndices( 1 , 0 , new Piece( 7 , 42 ) );
        game.demo( );
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        System.out.println( this.board.report( ) );
    }
}
```

When run:

```
Row: 0 | Column: 0 = null
Row: 0 | Column: 1 = null
Row: 0 | Column: 2 = null
Row: 0 | Column: 3 = null
Row: 0 | Column: 4 = null
Row: 0 | Column: 5 = null
Row: 0 | Column: 6 = null
Row: 0 | Column: 7 = null
Row: 1 | Column: 0 = Piece[teamId=7, id=42]
Row: 1 | Column: 1 = null
Row: 1 | Column: 2 = null
Row: 1 | Column: 3 = null
…
```

Comment: I think I might've given too little information to reverse engineer the game. I am unable to change anything about the Piece class as my professor doesn't allow it, so making it implement an interface does't work. Also Base is not a class but rather a value stored in another "Team" class and as a String in my grid. The teamId can be any int. After reading the comments, I'm gonna implement a container class storing a teamId and in case the Object is a Piece, its reference.  Also it stores what object is contained, for this I created an Enum storing all different possibilities. Thank you though!